# Which one is the larger value of $\min(x,y)$ and $\max(0,x+y-1)$, for all $x,y\in [0,1]$?

Tags: inequality

Which one is the larger value of $\min(x,y)$ and $\max(0,x+y-1)$, for all $x,y\in [0,1]$?

I'm trying as follows.

If $x\leq y$, then $$\min(x,y)=x$$

Now we have $x+y-1\leq 2y-1$.

Now I confused to conclude the value of
$$\max(0,x+y-1).$$

If $x> y$, then $$\min(x,y)=y$$

Now we have $x+y-1> 2y-1$.

Now I also confused to conclude the value of
$$\max(0,x+y-1).$$

So, can we compare the value of $\min(x,y)$ and $\max(0,x+y-1)$, for all $x,y\in [0,1]$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have $x-1\leq 0$ and $y-1\leq 0$ so $x+y-1$ is less or equal to both $x$ and $y$. Therefore $\min{(x,y)}\geq\max{(0,x+y-1)}$

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a proof based on probability and copulas theory for the sake of curiosity.

Let $C:[0,1]^{2}\to[0,1]$ be a copula.

Since it is nondecreasing in each coordinate and it has uniform margins, one has that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
C(u,v) \leq C(u,1) = u\\\\
C(u,v) \leq C(1,v) = v
\end{cases} \Rightarrow C(u,v)\leq\min\{u,v\}
\end{align*}
Moreover, we do also know that $C$ is 2-increasing. Particularly, $V_{C}([u,1]\times[v,1])\geq 0$, that is to say,
\begin{align*}
C(1,1) - C(u,1) - C(1,v) + C(u,v) \geq 0 \Rightarrow C(u,v)\geq u + v - 1
\end{align*}
Once $C(u,v)\geq 0$, we conclude that $C(u,v)\geq\max\{u+v-1,0\}$.

Gathering both results, one concludes that
\begin{align*}
\max\{x + y - 1,0\} \leq C(x,y) \leq \min\{x,y\} \Rightarrow \max\{x + y - 1,0\} \leq \min\{x,y\}
\end{align*}

More generally, if $(X,Y)\sim H$, $X\sim F$ and $Y\sim G$, where $H(x,y) = C(F(x),G(y))$, due to the Sklar's theorem, we can conclude that
\begin{align*}
\max\{F(x) + G(y) - 1,0\} \leq H(x,y) \leq \min\{F(x),G(y)\}
\end{align*}
for some copula $C$, and we are done.

Such result is known as the Fréchet-Hoeffding inequality.

Hopefully this helps!